# CKEditor on font-size change event

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg

Is there any way to capture an event when user has changed font-size?

I'm looking for something similar to this:

```
CKEDITOR.editor.getCommand('xxx').on('xxx', function(){

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.your_instance_name.on( 'change', function() {
    //  Code goes here
} );
```

Replace `your_instance_name` with your instance name.

Comment: What If I want to know what this change is, like font style or size?