# How to use callback after selecting font via ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

The thing is like that, I need to call a method after the user selects the font.

But I don't know where to edit his callback method.

I've tried this plugin https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/onchange, but it seems not work for my situation.

Comment: This seems to work for every change in ckeditor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19490380/ckeditor-on-font-size-change-event Then you'll need to filter the events in which the font family is changed.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.